# How do I add or setup the QuickLauch toolbar (previously available in XP and Vista) in WIndows7?

Tags: windows-7, taskbar, productivity

As a programmer working in Windows, I found the QuickLaunch area in the task bar to be a great boost to my productivity - all my most frequently used programs, right there, without having to open up the big start menu.

I even used to put a shortcut to my currently active Visual Studio projects there for quick access.

I have just installed Windows7, and I can't find the QuickLaunch option in the task bar properties anywhere.

How do I setup the QuickLaunch feature on Win7 (Windows 7)?

---

UPDATE: @MetalMikester noted this information on how to "bring back" the "old" QuickLaunch toolbar on [sevenforums.com here](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/888-quick-launch-enable-disable.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, you just drag your shortcut(s) down to the status bar.  It now acts both as a "quick launchbar" and task switcher now.  It takes a bit to get used to it, but eventually you don't notice it anymore.

Comment: Thanks @MetalMikester, I tried this at first, only to discover that the the shortcuts morph into tasks when you run an instance of that shortcut - and the shortcuts and running tasks become all intermingled, which I did not care for.  
  
I am going to vote you up, however - because I believe that if you found this useful and/or you "get used to it", other may also.

Comment: James, I would hold your nose and give it a try for a a while. You might just like it. I know it increased my productivity after I got used to it. They're going to have to pry Windows 7 from my cold dead hands if they want it back.

Comment: Also realize that the taskbar responds to win+num, win+ctl+num (both switch to running windows, win+num starts a new process), win+shift+num (run new) and win+shift+ctl+num (run as admin). I agree that if you try it for a while, you may come to prefer it.

Comment: @James McFarland - I found it a bit odd at first, but like I said, eventually you don't notice it anymore, it just becomes second nature.  The only reason it can still feel a bit weird for me is that I have 7 only on my laptop, still running Vista on my desktop and XP at work (soon going to Vista.) I agree with Shea - give it a try for a little while. When you've been used to something for years, a change will take a while to get accustomed to.

Comment: If all else fails, you can try the options here: http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/888-quick-launch-enable-disable.html

Comment: @MetalMikester - voted you up, and granted you the answer, not only for your insight, but especially for the link to sevenforums.com, which is the most accurate answer to the question - Thanks.

Comment: @MetalMikester - Your were right about getting used to it...I recently had to reinstall win7, and I decided to user the taskbar as you suggested - and I love it - way more than Quick Launch.  Here is what I do:
- for stuff I use a log: I arranged them how I like them, and pinned to taskbar.
- for less used stuff: I pinned to start menu - that gives me 2 things: some place out of site for things I want handy, but not on the taskbar, and extra space for launchables.
You and MS Rock for this, I am very happy.

Comment: Glad you like it!  I always try to give new things a few days/weeks of use before writing them off.  Let's face it, nobody likes to change years-old habits, but sometimes it's better in the long run. :)

Comment: @MetalMikester Right on.

Comment: So all you folks who "got used to it" - how do you start a new instance of an already-running program? Clicking the taskbar button just brings up the already-running instance. Depending on the program, sometimes right-clicking the taskbar button gives you an option to start a new instance, but that's no quicker than pinning to the Start Menu. How can I set up my taskbar so that the programs I want to launch quickly are always available, without jumping through extra hoops?

Answer (score 1):

If you have visual studio, just pin it to the taskbar (right click, pin to task bar). you can open new instances by using the mouse wheel click.

Comment: Or as an alternative: shift+click

Comment: You can also use Win + [num], where [num] will open the corresponding pinned application in whatever order you've set it to.

Comment: Actually, scratch that - it doesn't open a new instance if one is already running, it just minimizes it.

Comment: Darren: I discovered the ability to pin a task to the taskbar, however pinning results in taskbar becoming a jumble of shortcuts and running tasks, which at first look seemed awful to me.

Comment: PS: Darren, I am not voting this answer up (I apologize) - because I believe it is the antithesis of what I am trying to accomplish.

Comment: PPS: Darren: I use the Visual Studio project shortcuts to go directly into a project within Visual Studio, thus pinning Visual Studio generically does not suffice.

Comment: If you right click on the icon, you see an overview of recently opened items.

Comment: @CSarnia: win+ shift+ num always opens a new instance

Answer (score 1):

An additional comment on James McFarland's (I can't actually comment yet, so I'll simply add an answer). If you specify the normal Quick Launch folder path as your toolbar, then those applications that offer to add a shortcut to your quick launch will do so correctly.

On my system, the path to the quick launch folder is:

C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch

So if you create a new toolbar with that path, you'll have windows xp/vista style quick launch back entirely. I've been using this regularly now for about three weeks, and it works well for me in conjunction with Win7's taskbar.

Answer (score 0):

It appears to me that the QuickLaunch feature has been removed from the Win7 task bar.

However, the Win7 task bar allows the addition of toolbars to the task bar, and any folder can be referenced as a toolbar.

To do this, one can create their own "QuickLaunch" area as follows:

1. Create a folder in which to place the shortcuts you normally would keep in the QuickLaunch area. (I use a folder called "My QuickLaunch" under my *user* folder.)
2. Add your shortcuts to the folder.
3. Right-click on the task bar, and select "Toolbars | New Toolbar..."
4. In the "New Toolbar - Choose a folder" dialog, navigate to your new toolbar folder (e.g. *user*/My QuickLaunch) and click "Select Folder".
5. Your new toolbar appears in the taskbar, and can be positioned at the left (or anywhere you like).

In addition, you can customize the look by using the variuos task bar properties (small icons, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

There's an option in the taskbar properties to "combine only when task bar is full" (the default is combine, hide labels). When you switch to combine only when task bar is full, then running tasks will contain labels, just like the old task bar. Multiple instances will show up as multiple instances...  until the task bar fills up.

I tried it for a while, but it tends to look rather junky, and because I keep lots of "quick launch" icons in the task bar, it got to be a pain. So I went back to the default (hide labels).

Another useful trick is to click on an icon in the task bar, and drag up. That brings up the jump menu with a single click-and-drag.

I've also learned to love aero peek, which works both with alt-tab (don't tab too fast; a second or so and W7 will display the window corresponding to the task) and also with task images that pop up from mousing over the task bar (then mouse over each instance icon).

Lots of ways to use the new task bar; it does take some exploring and getting used to. I didn't like it initially, either, but I've come to really like it.